# From Wamp to Vagrant: Where is the MySQL database folder?

Tags: php, mysql, vagrant, wamp, puphpet

I got tired of Wamp breaking on every Windows updates so I tried to move to Vagrant with PuPHPet. So far so good. Only one problem: I can't find any of my MySQL databases!

So that was my set up with Wamp. Everyting was in sync with my Dropbox folder.

My websites were (still are) in this folder:

```
C:\Users\Martin\Dropbox\wamp\www
```

My databases were (still are) in this folder:

```
C:\Users\Martin\Dropbox\wamp\database
```

I can connect to my VM and see my websites. I can connect to my databases with HeidiSQL or MySQL Workbench, but NONE of my precious databases from Wamp are there.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have installed fresh mysql copy, so you must dump all the data from wamp instance and to import it in new (vagrant) mysql instance. is not good idea just to copy database files into new location.

Comment: So I need to do that via the command line?

Comment: WAMPServer has survived Windows 10 updates for moths now